# Accessing image from Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm pretty new to python and Google Cloud. I'm developing a website that needs to retrieve image from Cloud Storage and serve it to HTML. I deploy my Flask on App Engine and the image is can't be served it.

My Flask code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/translate')
def translate():
    return render_template("translate.html")

@app.route('/get-image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get("huruf")
        filepath = name + ".png"
        buc = storage_client.get_bucket(CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)
        blob = buc.blob(filepath)
        filename = blob.download_to_filename(filepath)
        return render_template("get-translate.html", nama=name, pict=filename)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for(translate))
```

Here is my HTML that input request:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Get Image - Isyaratku {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<br>
<form action="/get-image" method="post">
    <label for="huruf">Huruf :</label>
    <input type="text" name="huruf">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

And here is my HTML for a received image from Cloud Storage:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Get Translate - Isyaratku {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 

<h1>{{ nama }}</h1>

<img src="{{ pict }}" alt="gmb">

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you try to start your filepath by /tmp/? like that `filepath = "/tmp/" + name + ".png"`

Comment: What error do you get? Give us an example of filepath

Comment: Everything is good when I'm open my web, but it just the image can't display on HTML. What I desired in my web is a return image that I input in the form. For example, if I input "A" in the form, I hope the name of the picture "A.png" will be displayed